# Remove current directory if in Git repo

Tags: zsh, zshrc, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I am using the [Agnoster](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme) theme with Oh-my-zsh in iTerm2. Is it possible to hide the current directory if you're in a Git repo to avoid needless duplication, if so how?

[Here is a gist of my zsh setup](https://gist.github.com/jshjohnson/e1f92896b417c864bfc8)

[image]

Interestingly, [the actual Agnoster theme screenshot](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes#agnoster) does not duplicate the directory (as I was expecting)

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just fork the thing and add a conditional yourself.

Comment: The part in green should be the current **branch name**. If so it would not really be a duplication of the path. _But still a weird branch name_

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [@4ae1e1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1944784/4ae1e1) you can fork the theme and include a conditional.

In the directory prompt [here](https://gist.github.com/jshjohnson/e1f92896b417c864bfc8#file-agnoster-zsh-theme-L86-L89),

```
prompt_dir() {
   prompt_segment blue black '%~'
}
```

Include a conditional which would display directory information only if it was not in a git directory, like

```
prompt_dir() {
  if ! (git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1); then
     prompt_segment blue black '%~'
  fi
}
```